# RuntimeError: 1only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of size: : [4]

Tags: pytorch

How to get around the [following error](https://github.com/promach/gdas/blob/main/gdas.py#L380) with `nn.CrossEntrophyLoss()` ?

Note: I tried using `nn.BCELoss()`, but it resulted in different error: `ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([4])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([4, 3, 32, 32])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.`

[image: error]

Comment: please do not post screen shots of code/errors/logs - copy paste the relevant text and [format it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear: you are using a one-dimensional target tensor while your output prediction has spatial dimensions (a three-channel map).

When using [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html), your target must be dense (each element is a label id): something with a shape of `(batch_size,)`, where each element in the target belongs to `[0, num_classes[`. While the output consists of logits: `(batch_size, num_classes,)`, *i.e.* each class from each batch is assigned a value (*this is not yet a probability distribution*). In the spatial setting, you will have two additional dimensions (height and width), this is the case for dense predictions such as semantic segmentation. This will make your target have a shape of `(batch_size, height, width)`, and your output prediction `(batch_size, num_classes, height, width)`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using this [github commit](https://github.com/promach/gdas/commit/a659979a692fa9f8f5029c0455ec59b2d272d1de)

Note: the model output (`outputs1`) is wrong and should have the shape [BATCH_SIZE=4, NUMBER_OF_IMAGE_CLASSES=10].

```
In [11]: import torch

In [12]: a = torch.randn(4, 3, 32, 32)

In [13]: a.size()
Out[13]: torch.Size([4, 3, 32, 32])

In [14]: b = a.view(a.shape[0], -1)

In [15]: b.size()
Out[15]: torch.Size([4, 3072])

In [16]: c = torch.flatten(b)

In [17]: c.size()
Out[17]: torch.Size([12288])

In [18]: 

In [18]: import torch.nn as nn

In [19]: m_linear = nn.Linear(3*32*32, 10)

In [20]: d = m_linear(b)

In [21]: d.size()
Out[21]: torch.Size([4, 10])

In [22]:
```